# How to import a Maven project with Intellij Command line tool with command "idea pom.xml"?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I was watching [Get Started with Jhipster4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRREt1KB4Y8), In this tutorial this guy imported a maven project with below command:

```
idea pom.xml  <---- This is the Command line tool provided by Intellij guys
```

I also want to configure the same in my local, as suggested on [Intellij official website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-command-line-tools.html) tried to configure it but intellij is asking for the tool path, I have no idea what is should be, Please check the snapshot for more clarity.[image]

Comment: Tools | Create Command-line Launcher, then run it from the Terminal.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks, Please add this comment as an answer. It will surely help others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Tools` | **Create Command-line Launcher**, then run it from the Terminal.

Answer (score 6):

If you use spring boot and want to open from the terminal maven project its easy.

1. Open intellij
2. Navigate to Tools /Command Line Launcher
3. Add the default path - Just OK
4. Close the IDE
5. CD to the project from the terminal
6. type $ idea pom.xml

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVANj3gAWt8

Answer (score 0):

Quick addendum to previous posts: if you're on 64-bit Windows, you'll want to substitute "idea" with "idea64" in the examples above. Running the latest version of Intellij, there was no option to create a command-line launcher under Tools. Fortunately, this wasn't necessary for me. The Windows installer apparently took care of installing the bits and updating the path.